# Get operators from string returns decimal point together

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get operators from string using regex but when the operators numbers contains decimal points it is added to the operators.

How to exclude it from operators?

For example. I have a string with this math expression.

> 5+8 - then + operator should be extracted from string.
>
> 5.2+8 - then + operator should be extracted but now I am getting decimal point too.

decimal point numbers could be in the second operands too.

```
String[] operators = expression.replaceAll("^\\d+", "").split("\\d+");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically the portion covering the inclusion of a [mcve].

Comment: "get operators from string" give an example

Comment: Jonny Henly, the result from replaceAll / split is an good example of how extract operators from string. I am using it but I get the problem as I described in my question.

Comment: Suggesting that you include a [mcve] basically means: "Please [edit] your question to include your code with example input and output. If you're getting unexpected output then please include actual output and desired output, as well."

Comment: Hugo Zaragoza I have an string: "5+8" I need extract operator "+". When the string is "5.2+8" the replaceAll / split methods return a array with "." and "+" values.

Comment: Have you considered trying to extract what you want instead of eliminating what you don't want?

Comment: Have you tried, well, removing the periods?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Firstly, I'm not sure you want the `^` operator.

Secondly, If you are deleting all of the digits from the string, I'm not sure how you plan to split the string by digits.

I think you probably want to just split instead of replace and split using this bit of code:

```
String[] operators = expression.split("\\s+?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s+?")
```

This will remove all numbers and surrounding spaces, if any.

Alternatively, you might consider using an accept-what-you-want approach instead of eliminating-what-you-don't-want.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\/\\+\\-\\*]"); //plus whatever other operators you want to support
```

Comment: This answer boils down to "An example of what it is that you are trying to do would be helpful".

Comment: why all the down votes? This IS the correct answer to the question. Admittedly a poorly asked question originally, but it has been fixed.

Comment: This answer was posted before the question was answerable. Next time you should wait till the question is answerable.

Comment: Micker with it works when If I have decimal point before operator in first operand but if I have decimal point in second operand or another place in the string? How this regex shoud be?

Comment: @Radrik did you eliminate the `^` character? The behavior you describe is exactly what that does.

Comment: @JonnyHenly If it wasn't answerable, how did I get the answer right? If you read the original question carefully, it was answerable, not as good as SO or I would like, but answerable.